# How to Read & Write to same Blob file in Azure Function (.NET6)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

In Azure Function V1 (.NET4) code below worked fine

```
[FunctionName("run")]
public static HttpResponseMessage run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage request,
[Blob("sample.txt", FileAccess.Read)] Stream readStream,
[Blob("sample.txt", FileAccess.Write)] Stream writeStream) 
{
   //read & write to sample.txt stream works ok
}
```

But in Azure Function V4 (.NET 6), throws error that only 1 stream can be accessed

```
[FunctionName("run")]
public static HttpResponseMessage run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage request,
[Blob("sample.txt", FileAccess.Read)] Stream readStream,
[Blob("sample.txt", FileAccess.Write)] Stream writeStream) 
{
   //can ONLY use read stream or write stream, can't use both

}
```

How to Read & Write to same Blob file in Azure Function (.NET6)?

Note: issue only appears in Azure not in local debugging

Answer (score 2):

Final solution that worked in Azure Function V4 (.NET 6) is `BlobClient`

Code to use **BlobClient** to read/write files in blob storage

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Function1(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage incomingRequest,
[Blob("container-name/file-name.xml", FileAccess.ReadWrite)] BlobClient fileBlobClient)
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, This was working even though we have added 2 streams. Make sure your environment is up to date.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
        [Blob("samples-workitems/samples.txt", FileAccess.Read)] Stream readStream,
        [Blob("samples-workitems/samples.txt", FileAccess.Write)] Stream writeStream)
        {         
            Console.WriteLine("Blob length is "+ readStream.Length);

            string sample = "Sample Text";

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sample);
            writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        }
```

Considering this to be my initial text file

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Text file after post-trigger

[image]

Comment: Very nice to get a reply from someone at Azure. Worth the money paying azure bills :D
@SwethaKandikonda-MT what "solution" are you talking about? You mean upgrading the environment? Please note this issue only occurs in Azure not in local debugging.

Comment: @user160357, initially I didn't find anything you mention that this issue only appears in Azure and not in local debugging. We have reproduced that same in local and so have provided the solution that worked for us.

Comment: This does not work. It causes lots of exceptions saying ` Azure.Storage.Blobs: The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.`

Comment: @RichardBarraclough with Azure functions getting the correct NuGet packages is very important, especially if you're not running in isolated. As such I suspect your error is related to wrong NuGet. Start again with latest template available and slowly modify from there.